# Text highlighting and line breaking, NOT English language

Tags: line-breaking, languages, backgrounds

I've read the posts here about highliting text in documents.
For me combination of `\usepackage{color,soul}` and `\hl` is perfect and simple.
However it has two drawbacks:

- It seem to work only for latin alphabet, so I cannot write in polish using

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}`

If I use polish letters it gives error like this

`Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.13 ... duzych plikow, wielkosci rzdu gigabajtow}`

- It offer only yellow color.

What is the simplest way (least packages, code) to color background of NON-latin text with proper line breaking?

Comment: Try soulutf8 instead of soul, for the color use `\sethlcolor` (this is in the docu ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks it works perfectly. I regret I technically couldn't accept/upvote this comment as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use utf8 together with soul try the `soulutf8` package.

The color for `\hl` can be set with `\sethlcolor`, see the documentation.